# Is it possible to automatically detect redundant conditional statements?

Tags: javascript, compiler-optimization

In JavaScript, is it possible to automatically detect redundant if-statements so that they can be written more concisely? I want to automatically detect redundant if-statements in the code that I've written, but I'm not sure how feasible it would be to detect redundant if-statements automatically, or whether there are existing source code optimizers for this purpose.

```
var x = prompt("Enter a number:");
if(x == 5 || x == 10){
}

if(x==5){
console.log("This if-statement is redundant!");
}

if(x == 5){
console.log("This if-statement is redundant! Is there any way to merge redundant if-statements like this one?")
}


if(x==10){
console.log("x is 10.")
}
```

I tried to remove the redundant if-statements using Google's [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) (using the advanced optimization setting), but the redundant if-statements still were not eliminated:

```
 var a = prompt("Enter a number:");
 5 == a && console.log("This if-statement is redundant!");
 5 == a && console.log("This if-statement is redundant! Is there any way to merge redundant if-statements like this one?");
 10 == a && console.log("x is 10.");
```

Comment: @Overv Still, tools like this would be useful, since they would help to automate the task of optimizing a lengthy series of if-statements, and improve code readability. If I had a series of dozens of if-statements, I would want to automate the process of finding redundant if-statements.

Comment: Are you concerned with file size, or with execution performance? If file size, gzipping will likely take care of the redundancy. If performance, the modern compiled JS Engines should handle that end nicely. Write your code for clarity, and worry about tiny optimizations when you actually need them.

Comment: [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/editors/javascript_editor.jsp?ide=phpstorm) offers to merge the two middle `if`s. It can integrate with both JSLint and JSHint, and they both complain about the empty block in the first `if`.

Comment: @squint I'm also concerned with code readability. If redundant if-statements could be condensed, it would make the code easier to read.

Comment: [Webstorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/index.html) by Jetbrains has excellent javascript code quality introspection that can detect stuff like this.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Wait, I thought the redundant ifs were meant to *provide* readability. If I misunderstood, then why are you writing them like that in the first place?

Comment: @AndersonGreen If you’re that worried about readability, there might be a different way you should be structuring your code. Can you give us details about what you’re working on?

Comment: You could consider using a switch statement instead of ifs for your example. They make this kind of accident redundant.

Comment: ...also, if these if statements are so long that it's hard to see the redundant conditions being tested, then perhaps parts of the code need to be broken out into separate functions.

Comment: Post real code. As of right now, you're prematurely optimizing an extremely trivial case.

Comment: in fact looking at what closure compiler produced, it did remove the 1 and only redundant if statement, the very first one. the others are not redundant, they are what would be deemed a bug

Comment: @Xotic750 There is a remaining redundant if-statement, in the second and third lines of the optimized code:`5 == a && console.log("This if-statement is redundant!"); 
 5 == a && console.log("This if-statement is redundant! Is there any way to merge redundant if-statements like this one?");`

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd could be combined into one in this example, but they are not what I would call redundant, and in fact it is quite possible that modern JS engines would perform such an optimisation for you.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I'm just wondering - would you consider the `if` statements in http://jsfiddle.net/Y9HpD/ as redundant? I know your code is very simple, but outside of two `if` statements one right after another, that don't do much more than log something, when are they redundant to you? You can't always combine them just because they have the same condition. I'm sure you/we would expect the Closure Compiler to figure this out, but there are plenty of cases where there's logic in the `if `statement that invalidates the redundancy you think is there